# Java Versions: Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, keystore

I have read several responses to this error, but I still cannot figure out exactly how to fix it. I have narrowed down the problem to being differing versions of Java, but as someone who is relatively new to Android Studio (and coding in general) I cannot seem to figure out how to fix this. My app is already published, so I need to figure out how to use my current key store file and not generate a new one.

What I need help with is figuring out how to specify the Java JDK version being used in Android Studio. It looks like the key store file was generated using Java 17, but the build is using Java 11, which is not able to read the keystore file. Can someone please help me with this (Mac OS 11.6.1, Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 4). Here is what I have below.

I should also point out that for some reason I am not able to set the JDK version under my preferences like I have seen others been able to do. The option just doesn't exist for me.
[image]

I generated the keystore file using the command

`keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks`

Running `java -version` gives:

````
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-39, mixed mode, sharing)

Flutter doctor -v
```[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 11.6.1 20G224 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/dennisashford/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (4 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/dennisashford/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
    • VS Code at /Users/dennisashford/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.25.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • iPhone 12 (mobile)                 • CCFE8FB8-8AEB-4D19-9A7B-B5AEE7F5F411 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 97.0.4692.71```
````

Comment: do you solve this issue?

Comment: @Alexa289 unfortunately, no. I had to generate the key-store using the older format that is readable by Java 11. It is frustrating, but it worked for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

If you created you keystore with Java 17 it will have defaulted to PKCS12 format (even though you gave it the name keystore.jks).

Try using Java 17's keytool command to `-importkeystore` with the input being the PKCS12 version and the output being in JKS format (you must specify `-deststoretype JKS`). This may result in a JKS keystore readable by earlier versions of Java.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I would really like to be able to use a newer version of Java in Android Studio to read the key file, but I simply cannot figure it out. I updated my post to show that the option to chose the JDK path is simply not there for me. Is this the only option in Android Studio is to make it readable by an older Java version?